# Honda Accord losing coolant if aircon is turned on

Tags: honda, ac, accord, coolant-reservoir

I have a 2007 Honda Accord Euro all of a sudden now loses coolant whenever I use the aircon. When I drive with the aircon off, the level remains fixed but soon as I drive 20min with ac I realise the overflow reservoir is way below minimum. I can smell coolant when I open the bonnet but I cant see where it could be leaking.

I asked one mechanic and he said there is no relation between losing coolant and running ac. Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: The only link I can think of would be the A/C compressor drive system shares the serpentine belt with the water pump.  Perhaps your water pump is failing and the different loading when the A/C is on is causing it to leak.  I'd focus on finding where the coolant is going and that will likely lead you to the root problem.

Comment: Strange, if you turn the heating on with the AC compressor off does it still leak?

Comment: Took it to Honda they didnt do much, just flushed the system and put new coolant. Didnt have a problem since then